# No WiFi soon after installing V 17.04 and running wicd

Tags: networking, wireless

I started yesterday with a rather quick installation and used WLAN as Internet-connection. It worked well, but after running wicd, which showed all avialbale networks, and chosing tis one as "always connect ..." it disappeared.

I have access via LAN - but now wicd shows "kein Funknetzwerk gefunden" (no WiFi found).

How can I connect to WLAN now, as wicd fails?

Thaks very much in advance for your help.

Best Wishes

Gebhard